# angularjs error: not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope

I have a `$scope.data`, which contains an `[object Function]` with the name `function1`. I have verified this by logging it to the console.

When I try to call the function with the line `$scope.data.function1`, I get an error saying "Error: function1 is not a function"

What does this mean, and why can I not call this function?

EDIT: Some code

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, person, data) {
    $scope.person = person;
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log($scope.data);
```

I then call:

```
    $scope.data.function1();
```

Comment: what happens if you do $scope.data() ?

Comment: Can you post a little more code for context?

Comment: Is your $scope.data object being overwritten, thus removing the function1 function? I had an issue similar to this where jquery was being included twice on the page, and in between, my custom jquery functions were added, so when jquery was loaded the second time, the jquery object was overwritten and all my custom functions didn't exist.

Comment: @Zack no, it is not being overwritten

Comment: Could you post the result of that `console.log($scope.data);` call? Do you do anything in between those calls, or is it literally called right after the log?

Answer (score 0):

Hi David if you have to call this function then first you have to call like this:-

`$scope.data.function1()` from .js controller file.

And kindly cross check function first:-

it should be define like this in your controller:

```
$scope.data.function1 = function(){

};
```

Comment: It does have parentheses, I mistakenly omitted them.

Comment: Okay then can you please post more code or cross check have you defined your function like this..?